# Proving a topology is not induced by a metric

Tags: general-topology

I'm reading a proof where it requires to show that a topology is not induced by a metric. My question is:   What does it mean for a topology to be induced / not induced by a metric?

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Open_and_closed_sets.2C_topology_and_convergence).

Comment: "Is there a way to define a metric d on the space, such that the given topology is induced by the open balls for d?"

Comment: Suppose that it is defined by some metric, and derive a contradiction. Notice that metric spaces satisfy all separation axioms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be a topological space. We say that its topology is *induced by a metric* if there exists a metric on $X$ such that the set of open balls under that metric is a basis for the topology.